# How to join a table and count records in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

I have a `Collection` class which has many coins.
I am trying to select collections which have more than two coins.
Currently, I have no problem doing that through straight Ruby, but that's extremely inefficient.

My current code:

```
collections = Collection.all.select { |c| c.coins.count > 2 }
```

How do I achieve that through a `joins` call with Arel?

Thanks!

Comment: You should not use Collection as class name... There are several Ruby built in structures which require collections (e.g. rails model collections) and it may happen that you override some things which results in unexpected behaviour..

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Any ideas how to create the 'join'?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To answer my own question:

```
Collection.joins(:coins).group("coins.collection_id").having("count(coins.id) > 2")
```

Hat tip to [KJF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7129/kjf) who asked [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629744/activerecord-syntax-for-finding-all-items-with-an-average-rating-of-x-or-greater) and to [krakover](https://stackoverflow.com/users/528683/krakover) for answering it.

Answer (score 1):

Add counter_cache columns and query them.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column

Comment: Thanks. A counter cache is meant to save counting records on the fly. Given that my collections only include 2-5 coins each, this isn't an issue and I'd rather not store a separate column in the database. Any ideas how to write the `joins` query using Rails 3?