# Virtual Column to count record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

First, sorry for my English, I am totally new in ruby on rails even in very basic thing, so I hope you all can help me.

I have table Role and RoleUser
table Role have has_many relationship to RoleUser with role_id as foreign key
in table RoleUser is contain user_id, so I can call it 1 role have many users

and I want is to show all record in Role with additional field in every record called total_users,

total_users is in every record have role_id and count the user_id for every role, and put it in total_users,

I know this is must use the join table, but in rails I absolutely knew nothing about that, can you all give me a simple example how to do that.

and one more, same with case above, can I do for example Role.all and then the total_users in include in that without added it in database? is that use virtual column?
anyone have a good source of link to learn of that

I have following code in model

```
def with_filtering(params, holding_company_id)
  order = []
  if params[:sort].present?
    JSON.parse(params[:sort]).each do |data|
      order << "#{data['property']} #{data['direction']}"
    end
  end
  order = 'id ASC' if order.blank?

  if self.column_names.include? "holding_company_id"
    string_conditions = ["holding_company_id = :holding_company_id"]
    placeholder_conditions = { holding_company_id: holding_company_id.id }
  else
    string_conditions = []
    placeholder_conditions = {}
  end

  if params[:filter].present?
    JSON.parse(params[:filter]).each do |filter|
      if filter['operation'] == 'between'
        string_conditions << "#{filter['property']} >= :start_#{filter['property']} AND #{filter['property']} <= :end_#{filter['property']}"
        placeholder_conditions["start_#{filter['property']}".to_sym] = filter['value1']
        placeholder_conditions["end_#{filter['property']}".to_sym] = filter['value2']
      elsif filter['operation'] == 'like'
        string_conditions << "#{filter['property']} ilike :#{filter['property']}"
        placeholder_conditions["#{filter['property']}".to_sym] = "%#{filter['value1']}%"
      else
        string_conditions << "#{filter['property']} = :#{filter['property']}"
        placeholder_conditions["#{filter['property']}".to_sym] = filter['value1']
      end
    end
  end

  conditions = [string_conditions.join(' AND '), placeholder_conditions]

  total_count = where(conditions).count

  if params[:limit].blank? && params[:offset].blank?
    data = where(conditions).order(order)
  else
    data = where(conditions).limit(params[:limit].to_i).offset(params[:offset].to_i).order(order)
  end

  return data, total_count.to_s
end
```

And I have follwing code in controllers

```
def crud_index(model)
  data, total = Role.with_filtering(params, current_holding_company)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: { data: data, total_count: total }.to_json, status: 200 }
  end
end
```

My only purpose is to add virtual field called total_users, but i want added it in model and combine it with data in method with_filtering

Comment: Can you update your question more specific. Post on your models code and your expecting result. According to your comments on my answer, I'm not sure about your purpose of `how about return both`. You should describe your purpose in your question more clearly, instead of guessing by the readers.

Comment: oke Jaugar Chang, I have already added the entire code, i hope you can help.
anyway can i have both total_count and other value from code above,??

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: i use postgreSQL, why about that? is that something i can't do in postgre

Comment: SQLLite and MYSQL can support `select a.*,count(*) from a,b group by a.id`, but other DBMS cannot support that, so you have to provide all the column names to `group` and `select` method. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the models like this:

```
Class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :role_users
end

Class RoleUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belong_to :role
end
```

You could use select and joins to generate summary columns, but all the Role's attributes should be include in group.

```
roles = Role.select("roles.*, count(role_users.id) as total_users")
            .joins(:role_users)
            .group("roles.id")
```

Type those scripts in Rails console, Rails will generate a sql like :

```
SELECT roles.id, count(role_users.id) as total_users
FROM roles
INNER JOIN role_users
ON  roles.id = role_users.role_id
GROUP BY roles.id
```

Then you can use `roles.to_json` to see the result. The summary column `total_users` can be accessed in every member of roles.

And there are many other way can match your requirement. Such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004048/how-to-join-a-table-and-count-records-in-rails-3). There is a reference of [counter cache](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column).

My suggestion is after searching, you can test those method by rails console, it's a useful tool.

**UPDATE**

According to OP's update and comment, seems you have more works to do.

### STEP1: move `with_filtering` class method to controller

`with_filtering` handle a lot of parameter things to get conditions, it should be handled in controller instead of model. So we can transfer `with_filtering` into `conditions` and `orders` in controller.

```
class RolesController < ApplicationController

  def conditions(params, holding_company_id)
    if self.column_names.include? "holding_company_id"
      string_conditions = ["holding_company_id = :holding_company_id"]
      placeholder_conditions = { holding_company_id: holding_company_id.id }
    else
      string_conditions = []
      placeholder_conditions = {}
    end

    if params[:filter].present?
      JSON.parse(params[:filter]).each do |filter|
        if filter['operation'] == 'between'
          string_conditions << "#{filter['property']} >= :start_#{filter['property']} AND #{filter['property']} <= :end_#{filter['property']}"
          placeholder_conditions["start_#{filter['property']}".to_sym] = filter['value1']
          placeholder_conditions["end_#{filter['property']}".to_sym] = filter['value2']
        elsif filter['operation'] == 'like'
          string_conditions << "#{filter['property']} ilike :#{filter['property']}"
          placeholder_conditions["#{filter['property']}".to_sym] = "%#{filter['value1']}%"
        else
          string_conditions << "#{filter['property']} = :#{filter['property']}"
          placeholder_conditions["#{filter['property']}".to_sym] = filter['value1']
        end
      end
    end

    return [string_conditions.join(' AND '), placeholder_conditions]
  end

  def orders(params)
    ord = []
    if params[:sort].present?
      JSON.parse(params[:sort]).each do |data|
        ord << "#{data['property']} #{data['direction']}"
      end
    end
    ord = 'id ASC' if ord.blank?    
    return ord
  end
end
```

### STEP2: update action `crud_index` with `conditions` and `orders` to get total_count of Roles.

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  def crud_index(model)
    total = Role.where(conditions(params, current_holding_company)).count

    if params[:limit].blank? && params[:offset].blank?
      data = Role.where(conditions(params, current_holding_company)).order(orders(params))
    else
      data = Role.where(conditions(params, current_holding_company)).limit(params[:limit].to_i).offset(params[:offset].to_i).order(orders(params))
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: { data: data, total_count: total }.to_json, status: 200 }
    end
  end
end
```

### STEP3: update action `crud_index` to get total_users by every role.

Make sure the two previous steps is pass the test.

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  def crud_index(model)
    total = Role.where(conditions(params, current_holding_company)).count

    if params[:limit].blank? && params[:offset].blank?
      data = 
        Role.select(Role.column_names.map{|x| "Roles.#{x}"}.join(",") + " ,count(role_users.id) as total_users")
            .joins(:role_users)
            .group(Role.column_names.map{|x| "Roles.#{x}"}.join(","))
            .where(conditions(params, current_holding_company))
            .order(orders(params))
    else
      data =
        Role.select(Role.column_names.map{|x| "Roles.#{x}"}.join(",") + " ,count(role_users.id) as total_users")
            .joins(:role_users)
            .group(Role.column_names.map{|x| "Roles.#{x}"}.join(","))
            .where(conditions(params, current_holding_company))
            .order(orders(params))
            .limit(params[:limit].to_i)
            .offset(params[:offset].to_i).order(orders(params))
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: { data: data, total_count: total }.to_json, status: 200 }
    end
  end
end
```

**NOTE: step3 may need you to modify `conditions` and `orders` method to generate column_name with table_name prefix to avoid column name ambiguous error**

If you can make these steps through, I suggest you can try `will_paginate` to simplify the part of your code about `total_count` ,`limit` and `offset`.

Comment: thank you very much, it's so helpful

i tried it on rails 4, but it doesnt seem to work, any idea??
 Role.select(:id).group("roles.id").joins(:role_users).count("role_users.id")

Comment: @user3800631 Your scripts is different from what i offered. Your scripts will generate a sql like `select count(role_users.id) from ...`, it only return the count number. If my scripts cannot work at your rails console, can you post your input and output from your console? You could post it on your question.

Comment: Role.select("role_features.role_id").group("role_features.role_id").joins(:role_features).count
______
its work now, it is only return the count number, but how about return both, the count number and other field value,??
am i have to use 2 query or just 1??

Comment: wow its fantastic man,  its really cool..
i will try it step by step and hope it is works,
one more again, thank you bro...

Answer (score 0):

With what you explained, you could do something like this:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :role_users
  has_many :users

  def total_users
    self.users.count
  end
end
```

So you just need to call the `total_users` method on roles object which should get you what you desire. Something like this:

```
Role.first.total_users 
# this will give you the total users for the first role found in your database.
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You might want to [watch this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins) too:

```
#app/models/role.rb
Class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :role_users
   has_many :users, -> { select "users.*", "role_users.*", "count(role_users.user_id) as total_users" }, through: :role_users
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
@roles = Role.find params[:id]
@roles.users.each do |role|
   role.total_users
end
```

You can see more about how this works with a question I wrote some time ago - [Using Delegate With has_many In Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816020/using-delegate-with-has-many-in-rails)

--

It's where I learnt about [Alias columns](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp), which Ryan Bates uses to `count` certain values:

[image]